# Stress testing Quantum Uncertainty, a multi Phase Question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

I start this line of thinking i begin to seek the right questions to ask.
I am of humble origin, but even here i remember that it all starts  small somewhere. I think that even the greatest minds started as children,then they learned to question the world around them in logical and efficient ways in attempts to define the world in which they lived even sometimes poorly fitting into the worlds cogs. So i present here a set of late night brain bending questions that sizzle through my thoughts trying despite all logic to find a solution. these questions are presented in what little understanding that i have.

### 1. What are the result's of modifying the layers of a double slit experiment?

A. Is is possible to add a second layer of four slits for the results anticipating the unobserved test result's?

B. Can you stretch the Uncertainty of the particles location and path to the breaking point so as to define a Range of locations and paths it could be taking to its target?

C. What if you change the shape of the Slit Plate to a Curve?, if so which direction shows which changes?

D. What results could you get by observing the next line of Slits in the project?or perhaps only some of them?

D.1.Is it possible then to collapse half a wave form event while the other half proceeds unheeded?

### 2. Does anyone know of variations of the test that have been performed but produced different results?

A. If so, who performed them, with what equipment and when did they take place?

B. Did they record or publish the data harvested from those attempts?

3. Would this line of experiments allow for a multilayered experiment to force the wave to collapse into more than one particle?

### 4. At what range does the quantum uncertainty take effect?

A. how long does it last?,How long after being observed will a particle return to acting as a wave and a particle? Example( Will it always remember being measured? or forget after a certain amount of time?)

B.Can it then be measured after it has passed the slits, but before it strikes the last receiver plate?

### 5. If another particle is produced from collapsing part of an event but not all of it., where would it have come from?

A. What would the energy potential of that particle be?
B. What would the origin Point/source for this next particle be? 
C. How many electrons would it take being fired in such a manner to produce a positive energy gain if any?

6. How much of the wave's energy is lost passing through the slits if any?

Comment: In 99.9% of cases, a post with an enumerated list of questions is asking too many things. Please consider making one post per item in your list. You are much more likely to get answers if you do this.